# Logic implemented seems fine but there's a missing linkage required to output the desired array of nearby coordinate pairs

Tags: reactjs

I retrieve the available taxis' latitude and longitude coordinate pairs from the response.data.value of the LTA taxi availability API ([https://datamall.lta.gov.sg/content/datamall/en/dynamic-data.html](https://www.stackoverflow.com/)).

In CurCoord.js, I obtain the user's current coordinates.

In CountNearby.js, I implemented the logic to compare the available taxis' coordinates against the user's current coordinates to output an array of nearby coordinates.

However, there is no output rendered on the screen.

I've published my code on [https://github.com/OngJinHui/proj2_taxi.git](https://www.stackoverflow.com/).

On a side note, please click on the button "request temporary access to the demo server" on the [https://cors-anywhere.herokuapp.com/corsdemo](https://www.stackoverflow.com/) page to activate the cors session to start retrieving the data from the API call.

I tried to loop through the available taxis' coordinates to find those that were close by to the user's current coordinates but I'm not getting any output even when I've adjusted the difference to 0.01.

CountNearby.js

```
import CurCoord from './CurCoord';
import { useState } from "react";

const CountNearby = (props) => {

    const [closeToUserPoints, setCloseToUserPoints] = useState({});

    const handlerCurrentCoord = (latitude, longitude) => {

        props.latLon.forEach(individual_point => {
            if ((Math.abs(individual_point.Latitude - latitude) < 0.01) && 
                (Math.abs(individual_point.Longitude - longitude) < 0.01)) {
                    const placeholderSetOfPoints = {...closeToUserPoints}
                    placeholderSetOfPoints.append({nearbyLatitude: individual_point.Latitude, 
                                                   nearbyLongitude: individual_point.Longitude});
                    setCloseToUserPoints(placeholderSetOfPoints)
            }
        });

    };

    return (
        <div>
            <CurCoord onCurrentCoord = {handlerCurrentCoord} />
            <p>{closeToUserPoints[0]}</p>
        </div>
        
    );
};

export default CountNearby;
```

CurCoord.js

```
import React, { useState, useEffect } from 'react';

const CurCoord = (props) => {
  const [lat, setLat] = useState(null);
  const [lng, setLng] = useState(null);
  const [status, setStatus] = useState(null);

  const getLocation = () => {
    if (!navigator.geolocation) {
      setStatus('Geolocation is not supported by your browser');
    } else {
      setStatus('Locating...');
      navigator.geolocation.getCurrentPosition((position) => {
        setStatus(null);
        setLat(position.coords.latitude);
        setLng(position.coords.longitude);
      }, () => {
        setStatus('Unable to retrieve your location');
      });
      props.onCurrentCoord(lat, lng);
    }
  }

  useEffect(() => {
    getLocation();
  }, [lat, lng])

  return (
    <div className="App">
      <button onClick={getLocation}>Get Location</button>
      <h1>Coordinates</h1>
      <p>{status}</p>
      {lat && <p>Latitude: {lat}</p>}
      {lng && <p>Longitude: {lng}</p>}
    </div>
  );
}

export default CurCoord;
```

Thanks!